# "The named parameter 'color/shape' isn't defined" for TextButton

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was developing a GYM Management System using Andriod studio and VS code. So I was having this problem in my coding. Both 'color' and 'shape' named parameter isn't defined.

What can I try next?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_gym_manager/config/palette.dart';

class CustomCardRE extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;
  final String type;
  final Function add;
  final Function view;
  CustomCardRE({this.imagePath, this.type, this.add, this.view});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 5,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      color: Colors.grey[350],
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(
            imagePath,
            width: 84.0,
          ),
          Text(
            type,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          TextButton(
            color: Palette.secondaryColor,
            shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
            onPressed: view,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.list_alt,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 40.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'View $type',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            color: Palette.secondaryColor,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
            onPressed: add,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.add_circle_outline,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 40.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Add New $type',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The part where I was having trouble are here:

```
TextButton(
            color: Palette.secondaryColor,
            shape:  RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
            onPressed: view,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.list_alt,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 40.0,
                ),
```

```
TextButton(
            color: Palette.secondaryColor,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
            ),
            onPressed: add,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.add_circle_outline,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 40.0,
                ),
```

This is the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in TextButton you can provide the color and shape in the `style` property, like this:

```
TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text(""),
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
                      shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                        RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```